# Access webpack modules / variables from global scope

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have my react application compiled through from webpack. I'm using google recaptca's callback url like so:

```
<script defer src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=mywebpackfn'></script>
```

mywebpackfn is defined inside my webpack compiled js file. api.js can't find it. How can I get access to the webpack js scope from outside?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply expose your function to global scope. Inside your code

```
if( typeof window !== 'undefined' ) { // browser env
    window.mywebpackfn = yourFunction
}
```

Or something fancy to access global scope

```
// I know kung fu
(new Function('return this')()).mywebpackfn = yourFunction
```

Also you might want to compile your code as library https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library

Webpack config

```
output: {
  ..
  library: 'mywebpackfn',
  libraryTarget: 'window'
}
```

Comment: Currently I'm doing the first option you listed, but I was hoping there was a less hacky method. Second option seems like voodoo to me.

Comment: @tgun926 You could also compile your code as library https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with nodejs then you can create your node server outside of that webpack and api.js. In such a way that node server will be common to both webpack and api.js. 
In that way you can export your file from webpack that will still be required by api.js by that nodejs server.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things controlled via webpack, rather than assign to window directly in your codebase, you can use the `expose-loader`

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader

Or you can specify the `output.library` option of webpack which will expose the exports of your entry file as an object in global scope - you could export your callback from there